# Is there an effective, proper way to put very large public class enumerations below public methods that utilize them, to make the code more clean?

Tags: c++, class, enums

To summarize I have code like this

```
class c {
public:
    enum enumType { .... }; // huge!
    int function( enumType e );
private:
    ...    
}
```

The code works fine, but I would like to make it a little more clean.  The enumeration is two pages long, making the code difficult for the next guy. I guess I could put it in its own header file which I'm kinda thinking is the best solution.  I just wondered if there was a more elegant way to do this, without an external file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to use enum classes, which can be forward-declared:

```
class Foo {

    enum class bar;

    int foo(bar);
};

enum class Foo::bar {baz, blah};

int Foo::foo(bar b)
{
    return b == bar::baz ? 1:0;
}
```

Of course, using enum classes means some extra typing. But, as an extra bonus, you get better type safety.

Comment: Unscoped enums can also be forward-declared, but you have to specify the underlying type. Either way, it requires C++11.

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. That should work perfectly. Thanks!